# How to "Allow all Cookies" in chrome 114 using python (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

I am trying to select the first option in the Chrome cookies settings, i.e "**Allow All Cookies**"

but I am not able to select the option. I am using Python's Selenium module to achieve this task.

I have used these lines of code:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 1,
    "profile.block_third_party_cookies": False
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

It's selecting the second option, i.e. "**Block third party cookies in Incognito**".